# Why does Cumulative Layout Shift differ between PageSpeed Insights and Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, web-performance, core-web-vitals

Why does the [Cumulative Layout Shift metric](https://web.dev/cls) reported in Google's speed measurement tools, like [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/)/[PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) differ from what is reported in [Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome)?

Answer (score 3):

There is some nuance to how PageSpeed Insights (PSI) and Search Console report on Cumulative Layout Shift. The lab portion (Lighthouse) of PSI measures CLS until Lighthouse considers a page **fully loaded**. It does not measure beyond page-load.

[image]

Search Console and the field portion of the PSI uses [Chrome User Experience Report](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report) data and measures CLS until **unload**, stopping reporting *after pagehidden* (i.e this is inclusive of CLS beyond page-load). What this means is that the reporting you see in different tools can vary based on the **window of time** we are able to look at.

[image]

Lab tools like Lighthouse have to define a shorter window because they are focused on the experience during page load and optimize for delivering information about the experience quickly. Field data is able to take a more **holistic view** of the user-experience, which could include shifts caused after a page has loaded and the user has scrolled down to other interactions contributing to CLS.

Comment: This is great to know, thanks for taking the time to add this in. The biggest problem is then working out what is causing a large CLS in the field if PSI shows 0. What method would you suggest? I tried with paint flashing switched on and with layout shift regions but still get 0 shift, whereas field data says 0.99! Just wondered what a true expert would suggest :-) +1 to question and answer as people need to understand PSI better.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie That's an excellent question! Would you like to ask that as a new top-level question and I'll answer? There's two parts of an answer I can cover there.

Comment: thanks, I have added it as a question, hopefully doesn't get closed! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751471/how-to-find-cumulative-layout-shift-problems-if-page-speed-insights-says-one-thi

Comment: Has this changed, or does GSC not use the same time frame that PSI's field data uses? I'm seeing perfect field data (100% CLS = 0) on some domains while they're still getting "CLS  > 0.1" in GSC.

Comment: For anyone wondering: it seems to just be severely delayed. Pages that had been perfect in field data for a month or so have now finally turned "green" in GSC as well.