# Experience tab to measure CLS not visible in Devtools

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, lighthouse, cls

I am trying to fix CLS on my site. Lighthouse shows CLS issues but when I try to find CLS in the Performance tab, there is nothing there.

I heard that CLS won't appear in the Performance tab unless there are actual CLS issues, but in this case Lighthouse is clearly showing CLS but I cannot see anything in the Performance tab.

I am testing the following page: `https://dystopianstories.com/writing-competitions-contests/`

Any idea why CLS is not appearing in the Performance tab? Am I looking in the wrong place? Is it hidden Any help or advice would be appreciated! Thank you.

[Lighthouse results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScIyL.jpg)

[Performance tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGybY.jpg)

[Where it should be visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjHjr.jpg)

Comment: are you running in incognito mode? The performance tab tends to stop showing experience stuff if you have plugins that inject stuff into the page. Another thing is sometimes I find it only shows with CPU slowdown so try setting CPU slowdown to 4x. [Finally you could try my question (and self answer as nobody answered me) on how I found the issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751471/how-to-find-cumulative-layout-shift-problems-if-page-speed-insights-says-one-thi)

Comment: I have the same issue with Chrome 90 simply no Experience tab at all, I have set CPU throttling to 4, even slowed the network down but alas no Experience tab and no way to diagnose my logo shift on mobile - any other advice @GrahamRitchie