# Impact of csl gray label in Google Pagespeed Insight

Tags: google-pagespeed

Does the gray csl mark affect the overall csl rating based on 28 days among users, or are the gray marks only advisory?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNWO6.png - csl rate for 28 days
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcYTm.png - gray mark csl

Answer (score 0):

Grey marks are for things that do not affect the score but are useful for diagnostics / to see the root cause of things that **do** affect your score.

However in the first screenshot you do indeed have a CLS issue for about 30% of users that you need to address.

Now without knowing what animations your site has (and whether they are even causing the Layout Shifts!) the best I can do is offer a couple of links to resources that explain how to fix the composited animations issue:

[Stick to Compositor-Only Properties and Manage Layer Count - web.dev](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count)

[High Performance Animations - HTML5 rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

Hopefully they will help you fix that issue.

As for finding causes of CLS you should run a performance trace in developer tools, there is a section for Layout Shifts (normally near the top) that will help you find them.

You can find [info on this technique and a couple of others in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751471/how-to-find-cumulative-layout-shift-problems-if-page-speed-insights-says-one-thi)