# Origin Summary or Lab Data?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I am struggling a bit to do some final improvements to my site. Search Console complains about CLS being greater than 0.25 for Desktop.

Checking the URL:s that Search Console has pointed out I can see that that CLS for Origin Summary is above the value, but CLS for Lab Data is below the accepted value.

I am trying to understand the differens between Origin Summary and Lab Data. It says that Original Summary is a collection of 28 days, should I just wait for about 4 weeks now that the Lab Data shows an accepted value?

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWFGg.png)

Comment: See if [this answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63863748/2702894) helps you understand why you may see CLS on the Origin Summary but not on the Lab data and ways you can track the data yourself to ensure the problem doesn't occur at certain screen sizes etc. If you have any other questions after reading that let me know.

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682709/why-does-cumulative-layout-shift-differ-between-pagespeed-insights-and-search-co